Filtered colimit in a triangulated category
I am trying to make sense of the functor $\hat{H}$ in Definition 2.3.7 of Axiomatic Stable Homotopy Theory in the context of a monogenic stable homotopy category $\mathcal{C}$, which is a type of triangulated category with a monoidal structure (see Definition 1.1.4).
Denote the thick subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ generated by the unit object $S$ of the monoidal structure by $\mathcal{F}$. Let $H:\mathcal{F}\to\text{Ab}$ be an additive functor that sends distinguished triangles to exact sequences of abelian groups.
For each $X\in\mathcal{C}$, we form a filtered category $\Lambda(X)$. A 'typical object' in $\Lambda(X)$ is denoted $X_{\alpha}$. Then we define $\hat{H}(X)$ to be the colimit of $H(X_{\alpha})$ over $\Lambda(X)$. What I don't understand here is how to make sense of $H(X_{\alpha})$ since $H$ is defined on $\mathcal{F}$ and $X_{\alpha}$ consists of an object in $A\in\mathcal{F}$ together with a morphism $A\to X$. Yet $X$ is not necessarily contained in $\mathcal{F}$ so the morphism $A\to X$ might not be. Yet $H(A)$ does not depend on $X$ at all. I can see how to use $H$ to form a filtered diagram of abelian groups and then take the colimit, but this can't be the correct interpretation as it does not depend on the object $X$.
How do I explicitly make sense of $H(X_{\alpha})$ and $\hat{H}(X)$?

The original statement is perhaps a bit sloppy. You should interpret $H(X_\alpha)$ as being $H(Z)$ if $X_\alpha = (Z, u)$ where $Z$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ with $u: Z \to X$. It is true that $H(Z)$ does not depend on $X$, but the morphisms in $\Lambda_\mathcal{A}(X)$ absolutely do depend on $X$, and hence so does the colimit $\varinjlim H(X_\alpha)$.
For example as noted in the document, if $X$ is $\mathcal{A}$, then $X$ is the terminal object in $\Lambda_\mathcal{A}(X)$. For another example, if there are no nontrivial maps $Z \to X$ for some $Z \in \mathcal{A}$, then in the colimit, every map out of $Z$ will eventually go to zero: $H(Z)$ will play no interesting role in $\varinjlim H(X_\alpha)$.

Thanks for this. So the diagram of abelian groups for $X\in\mathcal{C}$ is the functor $\Lambda(X)\to\text{Ab}$ that sends the object $(Z,u)$ to $H(Z)$, and the morphism $(Z,u)\to(Z',u')$ given by an appropriate map $\varphi:Z\to Z'$ to $H(\varphi)$. Then $\hat{H}(X)$ is defined to be the colimit of the diagram $\Lambda(X)\to\text{Ab}$ of abelian groups. Is this correct?

Yes, that looks right.
